# Can't open downloaded file from downloadManager Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I load my website in a WebView, and I use Download Manager to download photo file from my website. The file downloaded successfully and I can found the file on Internal Storage/Download.

I store the file to Download Directory using Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD, here's my full code for download the file:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            if(isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));

                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I open my gallery photo, I unable to open the photo. It says "Can't Open" when I tap the photo. I check file details, and the file path refer to /storage/emulated/0/Download.

Any ideas why the image file path in my gallery showing different path? and how to solve this?

Comment: Well if the file comes from your website you can nicely compare the files. Start with file size.

Comment: `I can found the file on Internal Storage/Download. `. Did you tell the download manager where to store the file? Or what did you do exactly? And please tell that exact path too. How could we compare else?

Comment: `when I open my gallery photo,`. What did you do exactly? Using a Gallery app? Better. You found that file you said. You will have used a file explorer app on your device (if not then tell or do). Let the file explorer open the file.

Comment: can you tell me the format of you images..@HengkyMulyono

Comment: @Shivam the format is JPG.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your kind response. I store the downloaded file to my Download directory using Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD. I add the full code to my question. I look at the Download folder in my storage, and the file was there.

But, when I open gallery, there's a blank thumbnail, and I can't open my photo. In details menu, why its refer to /storage/emulated/0/Download? why its not refer to Internal Storage/download?

Comment: `I add the full code to my question`. I asked you to tell the full path of that download folder. So we can compare.

Comment: `I look at the Download folder in my storage`. But HOW DID YOU DO THAT? I asked you that before. Please start answering to the point!!

Comment: `why its not refer to Internal Storage/download` For the second time: That is not a full path! You should tell the full path in order to compare it with that other full path. And why did not you react on my suggestion to use a file explorer app? Do you want help or not?

Comment: @greenapps **_I look at the Download folder in my storage_** its not in code. I use a file explorer app. and I see the file properties, file location was in **Internal Storage/Download/downloaded_filename.jpg**. I don't understand how to see the full path from file explorer apps.

After that, I use gallery app for open the file. in properties, file location was in **/storage/emulated/0/Download/downloaded_filename.jpg**.

Comment: `Internal Storage/Download/...` Internal Storage is not the start of a path. Please find oud before we continue. Use ES File Explorer. And answer ALL my questions. And react on ALL suggestions. Dont forget my first comment. I really wonder why you do not give all requested info. Hurry up man!

Comment: @greenapps ok, I was browse the file using ES File Explorer. the full path is in /storage/emulated/0/Download/downloaded_filename.jpg, and I was able open the file from ES File Explorer. I was compare the file size between in Website, in EZ explorer and Gallery, the file size was same too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constant `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD`

You should set `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` instead.

Also there is more specific option like: `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`. It is suitable for image downloads.

Full list is described in documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html